# TypeError: cannot read property 'overload' of undefined(frida)

Tags: java, android, hook, frida

**I'm trying to hook m6517 method in the gha class:**

```
package o;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
    
public class gha {
    
        private static byte[] f4427 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=".getBytes();
    
        static {
            Package packageR = gha.class.getPackage();
            if (packageR != null) {
                packageR.getName();
            }
        }
    
        /* renamed from: ı  reason: contains not printable characters */
        public static String m6517(byte[] bArr) {
            int i;
            int length = bArr.length;
            byte[] bArr2 = new byte[(((length + 2) / 3) << 2)];
            int i2 = 0;
            while (i2 < length) {
                int i3 = i2;
                int i4 = 0;
                while (true) {
                    i = i2 + 3;
                    if (i3 >= i) {
                        break;
                    }
                    i4 <<= 8;
                    if (i3 < length) {
                        i4 |= bArr[i3] & 255;
                    }
                    i3++;
                }
                int i5 = (i2 / 3) << 2;
                byte[] bArr3 = f4427;
                bArr2[i5] = bArr3[(i4 >> 18) & 63];
                bArr2[i5 + 1] = bArr3[(i4 >> 12) & 63];
                byte b = 61;
                bArr2[i5 + 2] = i2 + 1 < length ? bArr3[(i4 >> 6) & 63] : 61;
                int i6 = i5 + 3;
                if (i2 + 2 < length) {
                    b = f4427[i4 & 63];
                }
                bArr2[i6] = b;
                i2 = i;
            }
            return new String(bArr2);
        }
    }
```

stackoverflow notify me that I should add some more details))

**And then it is printing me that:**

[image]

**MyHook:**

```
Java.perform(function () {
  var hash = Java.use("o.gha");
  hash.m6517.overload().implementation = function(str){
    console.log('original: ' + str);
    console.log('hashed: ' + hash.m6517(str));
    return hash.m6517(str);
  }
});
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?
stackoverflow notify me that I should add some more details))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's kinda look like base64 but that's not what ur asking for..

You need to pass method's signature

`m6517` receives byte array `[` means array in smali, and `B` is byte

```js
  hash.m6517.overload('[B').implementation = function(str){
  ...
```

btw, if you want to invoke it (it's static so no need for an instance) to pass byte array use

```js
m6517( Java.array('byte', [ 41, 41, 42, 43 ]) );
```

**Update:**

I see now it's renamed due to non printable characters

Either try to trace entire class or updated with the following script output

```js
Java.use('gha').class.getDeclaredMethods().forEach(function (method) {
  var methodName = method.toString();
  console.log("method name = " + methodName);
  try {
    // .. hook here
  } catch (e) { 
    console.error(methodName, e);
  }
});
```

Comment: It isn't working for me:( I want to overload it to get an argument and result